# What happens if you try to initialize a semaphore to a negative value

Tags: initialization, semaphore

What happens if you try to initialize a semaphore to a negative value

for example

```
semaphore s = -1;
```

I know that it does not make sense, but I want to know if you do that, will get error messages and your program won't execute; or there will be no error messages and you will face logical errors later.

Comment: Is this with some particular programming language, or is purely abstract? If a programming language is involved, be sure to include a tag for that language. Also, if this is about some particular programming language, why not _try_ it and _see_ what happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've said, it wouldn't make sense, as binary semaphores are supposed to only take the values 0 and 1, while counting semaphores are supposed to only take non-negative integer values.
However, to answer your question, I would assume that the reaction of the program to a semaphore initialized to a negative value would depend on the programming language.

I gave it a try with C# and I can say that

```
private static Semaphore _pool = new Semaphore(-1, 3);
```

returns

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Non-negative number required.
>   Parameter name: initialCount'

Answer (score 0):

Initializing a semaphore with a negative initial count is not useless. In fact it can be very useful.

Suppose you have a process running with unlimited threads and you notice that performance is being affected, so you'd want to dynamically set a limit of concurrent threads doing that (i.e. enable throttling).

Suppose you know that there are currently 20 concurrent threads and you want to start limiting to 15. Since you now want to reduce the number of threads, you'd want an `initialCount` of -5, but out of the box the Semaphore(Slim) won't allow you to do that.

I created a library that fixes this problem and allows you to start SemaphoreSlim with a negative initialCount, so if you set an initialCount of -5, the first 5 semaphores you release won't in fact release anything but only the 6th onwards will start actually releasing.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SemaphoreSlimThrottling
https://github.com/MarkCiliaVincenti/SemaphoreSlimThrottling